# LINQ diagonal sudoku filler

Tags: c#, .net, linq, sudoku

I have a sudoku generator.
my Algorithm is:

1. Fill entire sudoku grid with numbers to make a valid filled 9x9 grid.
2. Remove certain amount of numbers.
3. Check if is solvable.
4. Solve it with implementation of human solving techniques and rate difficulty depending on difficulty of techniques used.

Problem is in step 1. My brute force algorithm works perfectly for regular sudokus, but when i try to make diagonal sudokus (each of two diagonal in grid needs to have unique numbers too), the generating time increases to minutes. This is unacceptable.

So I fiqured out that good solution is to fill grid using linq.

My idea is:

1. Make collection of all possible cells and values (81 positions, each with 9 possible values).
2. Now create some sort of query of queryes like this:

   - From all possible cells, each position has to be present exactly once (eg. Cell 0,0 once, cell 1,1 once).
   - Each cell Value (1-9) must be unique in its row, cell and square (or diagonal if cell is on diagonal)
   - Returned combination has to be random each time

I am sure there are better solutions, but i dont see any yet.My skills with linq are fairly limited, so i would be very grateful for pointing me to the right directions. Thank you.

Comment: Linq will not make the algorithm faster. Linq is mainly a set of function that can make code more convenient to write. This convenience - because of its genericity (mainly because it applies to IEnumerable) - comes at a performance cost. What I suggest you to look at (if you don't want to rewrite your algorithm is a more efficient fashion), is to parallelize your algorithm 10 fold. Check out this MSDN help on how to do it. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460720.aspx

Comment: +1 Looks like a problem that can well be parallellized. Indeed it sometimes seems that linq is thought to magically solve a range of problems that it never intended to tackle. But the performance cost is not always true, I might add. For instance, set operations like Except() are way faster than manually coded nested foreach loops (when I do it, that is :)).

Comment: Vojtech, you might want to share your code at [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/faq).